# Footer issue in website

Tags: html, css

can u help see in my website http://www.noor-azmi.com/element/

The text in the footer should be central.

HTML

```
<footer>
         <div class ="container-fluid con-foot">
            <div id="foot1">Element Design Studio Pte Ltd <br><div id="copy"> Copyright 2017</div></div>
            <div id="footer-logo"><img src="image/Small-E-Logo.png"></div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Everything is fine, they are all grouped together in one div class con-foot, i wanna make con-foot centralised in the footer. i tried giving it a margin-left and margin-right auto but still cant.

By the way site is done in boostrap

Comment: did you read the bootstrap docs ? how to grid and stuff related ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.Hope it helps,

```
.con-foot {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
padding: 1rem;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the website removing `float: left;` from:

```
#foot {
  /* float: left; remove this line */ 
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```